# Elastic Search: How to Fetch Results for Multiple combinations of 3 or more fields

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elastic search, If i have documents with attribtutes say `Foo` `Bar` `Baz`   `Qux` and a bunch of other attributes.

I need to query in such a way that i get the results in below manner

**`Foo   Bar   Baz   Qux`**
`foo1  bar1  baz1  qux1`
`foo1  bar1  baz1  qux2`
`foo1  bar1  baz2  qux1`
`foo1  bar1  baz2  qux2`
`foo1  bar2  baz1  qux1`

Basically, I need all the combinations available with doc_count. Using the result, it can be said that  **With Foo=foo1, Bar=bar1, Baz=baz1, Qux=qux1, there are 20 documents/records**

Crude Way is, to use `terms` aggregation inside `terms`aggregation(4 times in this case).

There should be some easier way to do this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your mention with 4 embedded `terms` aggregation is a good one.

Another way would be to use a single `terms` aggregation with a `script` that would create a fake term made up of the four terms you're trying to aggregate, like this:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "combinations": {
          "terms": {
              "script": "[doc.foo.value, doc.bar.value, doc.baz.value, doc.qux.value].join(',')"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Note: make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order to use the above script aggregation.

Yet another solution in order to spare some cycles at search time would be to create that aggregate term at indexing time in another field, which you would then use in a single `terms` aggregation.

EDIT: 
If the order of results are important, and should be sorted based on doc_count of `foo`

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
        "primary": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "foo"
            },
           "aggs": {
               "combinations": {
                   "terms": {
                   "script": "[doc.foo.value, doc.bar.value, doc.baz.value, doc.qux.value].join(',')"
                   }
               }
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure how i missed the doc.

I've added one more top level terms aggregation for "foo" so that i get the results in the desired manner. Does that sound OK ?